# Duality between $D^b(\mathbb{Z})$ and $D(\mathrm{Solid})^\omega$

Tags: derived-categories, condensed-mathematics

My question is about Corollary 6.1(ii) in [Lectures on Condensed Mathematics](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf) by Scholze (page 41). Here is the claim:

> The derived category $D(\mathrm{Solid})$ is compactly generated, and the full subcategory $D(\mathrm{Solid})^{\omega}$ of compact objects consists of the bounded complexes all of whose terms are of the form $\Pi_{I} \mathbb{Z}$. The category $D(\mathrm{Solid})^{\omega}$ is contravariantly equivalent to the category $D^{b}(\mathbb{Z})$ via the functor
> $$
> C \mapsto R \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(C, \mathbb{Z}) : D^{b}(\mathbb{Z})^{\mathrm{op}} \rightarrow D(\mathrm{Solid})
> $$

I'm not quite understanding how to interpret this internal hom. I know how to view $R\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(C, \mathbb{Z})$ as an object in $D^b(\mathbb{Z})$, but I'm expecting to get an object in $D(\mathrm{Solid})$. One way to get from $D^b(\mathbb{Z})$ to $D(\mathrm{Solid})$ is to first move to $D(\mathrm{Cond}(Ab))$, then apply the derived solidification functor $(-)^{L\blacksquare}$. So should I think of this as
$$C \mapsto \left(\underline{R \underline{\vphantom{\_}\operatorname{Hom}}(C, \mathbb{Z})}\right)^{L\blacksquare}?$$
Alternatively, is there some reason $\underline{R \underline{\vphantom{\_}\operatorname{Hom}}(C, \mathbb{Z})}$ is solid? Or am I completely off base?

Edit: As mentioned in the lectures and by Dan below, the fact that every bounded complex of abelian groups can be resolved by a complex of free abelian groups means that the objects in the internal hom are direct products of $\mathbb{Z}$. This roughly answered my question about $\underline{R \underline{\vphantom{\_}\operatorname{Hom}}(C, \mathbb{Z})}$ being solid, but made me realize I don't know exactly what I mean by $\underline{R \underline{\vphantom{\_}\operatorname{Hom}}(C, \mathbb{Z})}$.

Comment: The 1-minute answer is that every object of $D^b(\mathbb Z)$ is given by a bounded complex all of whose terms are of the form $\bigoplus_I \mathbb Z$, and that applying $\mathrm{Hom}(-,\mathbb Z)$ turns those sums into products.

Comment: Thank you! This helps somewhat, but I still have some silly questions. I think this produces just a chain complex of abelian groups. How do I turn this into a chain complex of condensed abelian groups? Do we give everything the discrete topology?

Comment: Also, perhaps I'm misunderstanding notation: does $R\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}$ here refer to the internal hom of $D(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: You're suppose to think of $\prod_I \mathbb Z$ as the condensed cartesian product, not the abelian group $\prod_I \mathbb Z$ with the discrete topology. And the homs are the internal derived Hom, but if you decide to represent your objects of $D^b(\mathbb Z)$ by bounded complexes of free abelian groups then this coincides with the internal Hom of chain complexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation is actually amibiguous which I guess causes the confusion.  In fact this $\underline{RHom}(C,\mathbb{Z})$ stands for the internal hom from $C$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ in derived $\textit{condensed}$ abelian groups.  Here $C$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ start in $D(\mathbb{Z})$ but we can view that as the ``discrete" full subcategory of $D(Cond(\mathbb{Z}))$.  As Dan indicates in the comments, this internal RHom is calculated by representing $C$ by a bounded complex of free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and then noting that $\underline{RHom}(\oplus_I \mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=\prod_I\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask for some clarification about what ``discrete'' means here? Is the embedding $D(\mathbb{Z}) \to D(\mathrm{Cond}(\mathbb{Z}))$ given by the derived functor of $A \mapsto \underline{A_{\text{discrete}}} : \mathrm{Ab} \to \mathrm{Cond}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: In a word, yes!  Note also that $A\mapsto \underline{A_{discrete}}$ is an exact functor so this derived functor is not very subtle.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure I'm understanding everything precisely.